PDO driver mysql is not supported displays while running an Admidio-based project's container
Recently I tried to fabricate a Docker container in my Admidio-based web application, but I encountered to a tiny error:
When I open the localhost:8080 web page it displays the following message:
"The requested PDO driver mysql is not supported"
I modified several times the docker-compose.yaml file and the Dockerfile.
Here it is the docker-compose.yaml:
services:
  php:
    image: php:7.4-apache
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    volumes:
     - /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project:/var/www/html
    environment:
      - APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
      - APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
      - PHP_EXTENSION=pdo_mysql
    depends_on:
      - db
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8077:80'
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=db
      #- PMA_ARBITRARY=1
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - '5506:3306'
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: TRUE
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 1234567
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1234567

And the Dockerfile:
FROM php:7.4-apache

WORKDIR /var/www/html/

RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql

COPY . /var/www/html/

RUN chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html/
RUN chmod 755 /var/www/html/

# start Apache2 on image start

EXPOSE 80

# Use the official MySQL image as a base
FROM mysql:latest

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
ADD . /app

# Set the default user for the MySQL image
USER mysql

# Set environment variables for the new user
ENV MYSQL_USER=external_user
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=my_database

# Run the following commands to create the new user and grant them the necessary permissions
RUN mysql -u root -p -e "CREATE USER '$MYSQL_USER'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '$MYSQL_PASSWORD';"
RUN mysql -u root -p -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $MYSQL_DATABASE.* TO '$MYSQL_USER'@'%';"
RUN mysql -u root -p -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"

# Expose port 3306 to allow connections to the database
EXPOSE 3306

# Start the MySQL server when the container is run
CMD ["mysqld"]

Thank you!
